# How to output a variable if "is" is false?

Tags: c#, html, if-statement

So I'm writing some code for a website with c#.

And I've used the "is" in my if and then created a variable for output like this:

```
if (test is Class1 item)
{
   <p>@item.title</p>

}
else if(!(test is Class1 item))
{
   <p>@item.somethingelse</p>

}
```

Note: all the classes have a common interface.

So my question is, how do I create a variable from type e.g. Class2 in the second if-else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already have a variable - `test`. If all you've shown is that it *isn't* a `Class1`, there's no point in declaring a new variable, as you have no more useful information. If you want to declare a variable of type `Class2`, you'd need something like `if (test is Class2 item)`. It's not really clear what you're trying to do though.

Comment: `if (test is Class2 item)`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski But what if there is: Class2, Class3, Class4, etc... My point is that I don't want to create a thousand if-else's.

Comment: Then this is an XY problem. If you have lots of different classes and need to do something different for each of them, you need all those `if` blocks. If you've got lots of different classes but you want to do the *same* thing for each of them, then you probably want to use a base class or an interface. But we don't have any context for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet alright so there is no way to do it in this style and form then?

Comment: He can use a switch though

Comment: @LegacyCode that's what I'm trying to avoid, because I don't know all possible Classes.

Comment: If you don't know all the classes, how do you know that there's a "title" field or property? Again, it's very unclear what your situation is, which makes it really hard to help you. You asked about creating a variable for Class2, and we gave you an answer for that - now apparently that's not really what you want to know. Please help us to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet well they all have a common interface so that's where I know that there is a "title" property. Also I don't want it just for Class2.

Comment: The part with the common interface... You should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: @LegacyCode yep sry

Comment: In your posted code, you don't have to check for a negative condition in an `else if`. Just use a plain `else` - you only get there when the if-condition failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this could be of help, as an example:

```
    interface IHasTitle
    {
        string GetTitle { get; }
    }

    public class Class1 : IHasTitle
    {
         #region IHasTitle
          public string GetTitle { get { return title; } }
        #endregion

        public string title { get; set; }

       //rest of the class

    }

    public class Class2 : IHasTitle
    {
        #region IHasTitle
        public string GetTitle { get { return title; } }
        #endregion

        public string title { get; set; }

        //rest of the class

    }

    public class Class3
    {
        public string title { get; set; }

        //rest of the class

    }
```

now in your if blocks you only need

```
        if (test is IHasTitle item)
        {
           < p > @item.GetTitle </ p >
        }
```

This will work for all clases that implement the IHasTitle interface... So clases 1 & 2 will return a title class 3 will not.

Comment: This would normally work, but the thing is that the classes don't implement their properties from their common interface. But instead have different properties from an instance of system.attribute. I'ts very confusing I know.

Comment: @GogoDev: It's confusing because you never showed your actual classes in the question.

Comment: @Flater yes sry, but this is for my company and I'd rather not show much of it. My example wasn't very good I know.

Comment: @GogoDev: If you can't show proprietary or personal information, then create a demo script that reproduces the problem without revealing information you don't want it to (commonly known as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: @Flater well that's I've tried to do...

Comment: @GogoDev: Where? You haven't shown *any* class declarations. You've said in one place that you know there's a `title` property because of the interface, but in these comments you've said that they *don't* implement properties from the common interface. Trying to help in this situation is like wading through quicksand.